# ThinkPad P15 with hard drive encryption and docking station with external monitors : startup password prompt does not appear on external monitors

Tags: boot, thinkpad, external-display, disk-encryption, docking-station

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad P15 connected to a USB-C docking station, itself connected to two monitors. I do not want to use the laptop's monitor (compared to the other monitors, it is too small and its DPI is too high). Therefore I use it closed down.

Also, I use a hard drive encryption system, which, upon starting my computer, asks me for a password on a special startup screen (before Windows ever starts).

This works, with at least one drawback : When using the laptop closed down, the special startup screen will not be displayed on one of the external monitors connected via the docking station, and I have to open up the laptop's integrated monitor to see it and enter the password.

Interestingly, and incidentally, the mouse and keyboard are working - even though they too are connected via the docking station.

I remember another, older Lenovo laptop I had (T560 I think) with a different docking station (one where you click the computer down on it instead of connecting a USB cable) with which I would actually see the the special startup screen (albeit with a strange resolution/format) on one of the monitors connected via the docking station.

Can I do anything about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.
Just have a look into BIOS settings - in menu "Display" you should see the choices for the display which will be used during system start.
You can choose "internal LCD", "external HDMI" or "external USB-C".
"USB-C" is only working for directly connected USB-C monitors, not working for monitors via USB-C-Dock.
But you may connect one of your external monitors directly to the HDMI output at the P15 (not the output of the dock), and configure the "external HDMI" display for startup. You may leave your second monitor connected via USB-C-Dock. In this case HDMI monitor (if connected) will display your startup (Bitlocker) screen instead of the internal display, and after windows has started, both monitors will work.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same problem indeed, and I think your solution works, except it doesn't apply to me as I do not want to have to plug/unplug the HDMI when taking the laptop off the docking station / bringing it back to it.